# best way to store a single time use record in redis using golang

Tags: go, redis

I am using golang and go-redis package
I would like to store a key-value pair in redis (e.g one time token). When this token is read, I generate a permanent token. But the one time token should be deleted once I have read the value. This is to avoid fast-replay attack. What is the best way to implement this. I have been thinking of mutex.

Comment: you can perhaps use a redis lua script to 1: read the token and then intermediately 2. delete the token. If you cant read someone else got there before you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a perfect use case for the `MULTI-EXEC` functionality:

```
MULTI
GET key
DELETE key
EXEC
```

Or in go:

```
pipe := client.TxPipeline()

get := pipe.Get("key")
pipe.Del("key")

_, err := pipe.Exec()
fmt.Println(get.Val(), err)
```

This will ensure that both commands execute in a transaction, so the key will either be retrieved and deleted or not retrieved at all.